# Share variable between two lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, anonymous-function, capture

I want to be able to share a variable in the containing scope between two lambda functions. I have the following:

```
void holdAdd(const Rect& rectangle, Hold anonymousHeld, Hold anonymousFinish) {
    std::map<int,bool> identifierCollection;

    HoldFinish holdFinish = [=](const int& identifier) mutable {
        if (identifierCollection.count(identifier) == 0) return;

        identifierCollection.erase(identifier);
        anonymousFinish();
    };

    holdCollisionCollection.push_back([=](const int& identifier, const Vec2& point) mutable {
        if (rectangle.containsPoint(point)) {
            identifierCollection[identifier] = true;
            anonymousHeld();
        } else {
            holdFinish(identifier);
        }
    });
    holdFinishCollection.push_back(holdFinish);
}
```

I can see in the debugger that `holdFinish` is pointing to a different implementation of `identifierCollection` than in the 2nd lambda function.

If I use `[=, &identifierCollection]` it throws a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` whether I use `mutable` or not.

My experience with other languages that implement inline functions is that this should be possible. For instance in javascript:

```
var a = 10;
var b = function() {
    a += 2;
}
var c = function() {
    a += 3;
}
b();
c();
alert(a);
```

Would alert `15`.

What do I have to do to get both lambda functions to reference the same identifierCollection implementation? So that it behaves in the same way as the javascript example.

Comment: So the problem is that when you capture by value you've captured by value, and when you capture by reference you've captured a dangling reference to a local variable.... You'll have to decide what you want the lifetime of the object to be.

Comment: does `[&]` work? try making the map `static`

Comment: Wrap the map in a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So you're saying that `identifierCollection` goes out of scope because the call to `holdAdd` ended? That I would have to manually retain `identifierCollection`? That unlike in javascript, c++ does not retain the data it references from an external scope?

Comment: You need to manage the lifetime of C++ objects yourself; or if you use a `shared_ptr` it will be done automatically.

Comment: @richardjsimkins: That's right. There are very, very few similarities between C++ and JavaScript of all things.

Comment: @twentylemon: That's very unlikely to be the desired solution. It completely changes the semantics of the function.

Comment: Why are you using `const int&`?

Comment: @richardjsimkins: In your Javascript example, `a` is in scope while `b()` and `c()` are **actually running**, so it is valid for both of them to modify `a`. That is not the case in your C++ example. You created the lambdas and **merely stored them**, but you are **not actually running them** while `identifierCollection` is still in scope.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know C++ isn't JavaScript but it not retaining the referenced variables seems like an insensible default. OK, how would I use shared_ptr?

Comment: The two functions that share state, should be member functions of an object holding that state.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I run them elsewhere. If I ran them elsewhere in the JavaScript example it would still work.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's how my old code did it. I wanted it to work with C++'s lambda functions though.

Comment: @richardjsimkins: It's quite sensible in fact: it makes the lifetimes of objects clear and easy to reason about. C++ is not "high level" like a scripting language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike in some scripting languages, `identifierCollection`'s lifetime won't be extended simply because you captured it into a closure. So as soon as you change that `[=]` for a `[&]` to capture by reference, it's a dangling reference to a local variable that you're capturing.

You'll have to manage the lifetime of `identifierCollection` yourself; frankly, this sounds like the perfect opportunity for a shared pointer, captured by value into each lambda. The dynamically-allocated map it wraps will literally exist for as long as you need it to.

```
void holdAdd(const Rect& rectangle, Hold anonymousHeld, Hold anonymousFinish)
{
    auto identifierCollection = std::make_shared<std::map<int,bool>>();

    HoldFinish holdFinish = [=](const int& identifier) mutable {
        if (identifierCollection->count(identifier) == 0) return;

        identifierCollection->erase(identifier);
        anonymousFinish();
    };

    holdCollisionCollection.push_back([=](const int& identifier, const Vec2& point) mutable {
        if (rectangle.containsPoint(point)) {
            (*identifierCollection)[identifier] = true;
            anonymousHeld();
        } else {
            holdFinish(identifier);
        }
    });
    holdFinishCollection.push_back(holdFinish);
}
```

Comment: Works as expected now. Brilliant! Thanks :)

Comment: Though JavaScript is not a scripting language, despite its name ;) I would say it's more a symptom of C++ not having garbage collection. So I think it would be better if the answer said "Unlike in languages that have garbage collection"

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the map in a `std::shared_ptr` then the lifetime will be managed automatically. Your lambda can then capture by value and it will get a reference to the map whose lifetime remains valid until the lambda function returns.

To do this, change your map definition to:

```
auto identifierCollection = std::make_shared<std::map<int,bool>>();
```

And then any calls to member functions of the map need to change from using `.` to `->` (as it is now a pointer).