# Share object between two lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, shared-ptr

I am trying to share the same object (in my case, a string) between to lambdas using shared_ptr:

```
auto fileToLoad = make_shared<string>();
    StartAsync(
        [=]()
    {

        QDir dir(dirPath.c_str());
        QString fileExtension(fileExt.c_str());

        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            auto files = dir.entryList(QStringList() << fileExtension << fileExtension.toUpper(), QDir::Files);
            if (!files.empty())
            {
                //fileToLoad.reset(new string(files.first().toUtf8().constData()));
                fileToLoad = make_shared<string>(files.first().toUtf8().constData());
                break;
            }

            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
        }
    },
        [=]()
    {
        if (fileToLoad == nullptr)
        {
            DisplayMessage("Timeout reached");
        }
        else
        {
            doFunc(*fileToLoad);
        }
    });
```

After many attempts I have still not been able to make it work as I want: to store fileToLoad in the first lambda and use it in the second. Or it fails to compile due to qualifiers (const), or it compiles but 'fileToLoad' remains empty.

As you can see I am trying to notify if a file has appeared in a folder, using StartAsync function, which takes 2 lambdas (this function basically creates QObjects and move them to background thread and then makes some connections between signals and slots).

Edit:

StartAsync: takes a lambda of a task (lengthy work), and a lambda of post task (UI updates)

```
void MainWidget::StartAsync(function<void()> func, function<void()> postTask)
{
    AsyncTask* task = new AsyncTask(func, [=]() { if (postTask != nullptr) { postTask(); HideProgressBar(); }});
    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    task->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, &QThread::started, this, &MainWidget::ShowProgressBar);
    connect(thread, &QThread::started, task, &AsyncTask::RunTask);
    connect(task, &AsyncTask::TaskFinished, task, &AsyncTask::RunPostTask);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, task, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);

    thread->start();
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is `StartAsync`? What does it do? Do you have a link to a reference about it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude edited

Comment: If I should hazard a guess, though, it has to be the `fileToLoad = make_shared<string>` part. This creates a whole new `shared_ptr<string>` object, totally unrelated to the one captured by the two lambdas. Maybe skip the shared pointer thing, and just capture a plain `std::string` by reference?

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that lambda will destroy the local object even if it is captured by reference after going out of scope, that is why I am using the shared_ptr thing as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823836/share-variable-between-two-lambdas

Comment: It's a life-time issue. A variable whose life-time ends will be destructed, but it's only that variable! If the variable is a pointer or a reference, it won't affect the value being pointed to or referenced.

Comment: `StartAsync` doesn't take lambdas, but functions, they are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a new value to a `std::shared_ptr` - you create a new shared value, that doesn't have any connection with the previous one (you can have a look at counters of both shared_ptrs). You should change

```
fileToLoad = make_shared<string>(files.first().toUtf8().constData());
```

to

```
*fileToLoad  = files.first().toUtf8().constData()
```

(of course checking beforehand that fileToLoad  isn't null)

Answer (score 0):

You code won't work, because in first lambda you overwrite the temporary pointer inside lambda. What you can do is overwrite `std::string` behind the pointer and it should work fine:

```
auto fileToLoad = make_shared<string>();
    StartAsync(
        [=]()
    {

        QDir dir(dirPath.c_str());
        QString fileExtension(fileExt.c_str());

        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            auto files = dir.entryList(QStringList() << fileExtension << fileExtension.toUpper(), QDir::Files);
            if (!files.empty())
            {
                //fileToLoad.reset(new string(files.first().toUtf8().constData()));
                *fileToLoad = files.first().toStdString();
                break;
            }

            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
        }
    },
        [=]()
    {
        if (fileToLoad == nullptr)
        {
            DisplayMessage("Timeout reached");
        }
        else
        {
            doFunc(*fileToLoad);
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what happens when the two lambdas are accessed simultaneously?

Comment: It is UB, yet `StartAsync` code proves that they never are ;)